# Current Transformator "Rb"

Tags: current-measurement, datasheet, current-transformer

While i was looking for STPM32 Energy meter chip, i saw a ratio named Rb[V/A]. I really searched at Google for it but really can't be sure what is exatcly is.
And my X5 currunt transformer's datasheet really doesn't help me. The ratio Rb is at page 48 above and middle of page. And datasheet right below.

Thanks

[STPM32DATASHEET](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/d9/c1/c6/3d/09/7f/4f/7b/DM00111861.pdf/files/DM00111861.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00111861.pdf)

Comment: It's not Rb[V/A], it's Rb/N and the units are volts per amp. 1A through the CT is Rb/N volts out of the CT.

Comment: Yes, i have forgatten to write decimation N. But still i could not understand what resistor value is. You meaned its only resistance on 1A?

Answer (score 1):

\$R_b\$ is the *burden* resistor chosen for converting the current induced in the secondary of the current transformer into a voltage.

The choice of resistor is up to you.

> A burden resistor connected across the secondary produces an output voltage proportional to the resistor value, based on the amount of current flowing through it. With our 1:10 turns ratio transformer that produces a 10:1 current ratio, a burden resistor can be selected to produce the voltage we want. If 1A on the primary produces 0.1A on the secondary, then by Ohm's law, 0.1 times the burden resistor will result in an output voltage per amp.
>
> *-- [Exploring Current Transformer Applications](http://www.powerelectronics.com/content/exploring-current-transformer-applications)*

Comment: +1 Of course if the burden resistor is too high in value for the current transformer, the accuracy will be compromised.

Comment: Of course. The perfect burden resistance is equal to the resistance of the coil.

Comment: I always "assert" that it is only voltage that is induced (as per Faraday) and current is as a result of the induced voltage and load (burden on this occasion).

Comment: Perfect answer, best regards.